# Query on Device Twin array properties

Tags: azure-iot-hub

how can query on a reported twin that is an array of strings
for example :

```
"SupportedCommands": [
                "firmwareUpdate",
                "diagnostics",
                "getLog",
                "calculateHash"
            ]
```

I checked some command like

```
WHERE CONTAINS(array, string)
```

or

```
WHERE [string] IN [array]
```

but no one worked

Answer (score 1):

> When querying twins and jobs the only supported function is:
>
> IS_DEFINED(property)

see more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language#functions).

As a workaround can be used a querying in the two steps, where the first one (such as a pre-querying process happen on the IoT Hub service side) will returned all twins based on the value of the property, see the following example:

```
SELECT 
  deviceId, properties.reported.SupportedCommands 
FROM devices 
WHERE properties.reported.SupportedCommands NIN [ null, [], ['abc', '123']  ]
```

the second step will be on the client side using the LINQ statements, see the following example:

```
var dummy = new { SupportedCommands = new string[] { } };
var query2 = (await query1.GetNextAsJsonAsync()).Where(i => JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(i, dummy).SupportedCommands.Contains("getLog"));
```

Comment: Thanks for respond. In client side, I am using node js sdk. Temporarily by using a corresponding statement solved my problem .  But expect that iothub supports a native and straight query.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM devices 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(tags.SupportedCommands,'firmwareUpdate')
```

I hope it will be useful to you.

[Query on IoT Hub to find a device using properties list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68080914/query-on-iot-hub-to-find-a-device-using-properties-list)