# Query on IoT Hub to find a device using properties list

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

I would like the list of devices that have specific characteristics.
In the tags there is a property of type array:

```
"tags": {     
    "types": [
        "type A",
        "type B"
    ]
}
```

I've tried doing fancy queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM devices WHERE tags.details.types.contains('type A' )
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM devices WHERE 'type A' IN tags.details.types
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM devices WHERE tags.details.types IN ['type A']
```

Comment: Same problem: [Query on Device Twin array properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64028885/query-on-device-twin-array-properties)

Comment: [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-contains)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to the documentation [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-contains)

The correct way to make a query to retrieve data belonging to an array is:

```
SELECT * FROM devices WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(tags.details.types,'type A')
```